# Trained model returns constant value independent of input

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to train a simple model on data that has seven inputs and one output. My dataframe basically looks like this:

```
    x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  Re  mean Cd
0   15  21  15  15  21  21  200 0.007524
1   15  21  15  15  21  21  400 0.007722
2   15  21  15  15  21  21  600 0.007892
3   15  21  15  15  21  23  200 0.010272
4   15  21  15  15  21  23  400 0.009638
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

From there I want to train a very simple model like this:

```
# Load the dataframe that was saved in read_files.py
df = pd.read_csv("tmp/df.csv",index_col=0)

# Split data into train and test sets
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
# Create a shallow copy of the data
train_features = train.copy()
test_features = test.copy()
# Remove the "mean Cd" column from the features and use it as label
train_labels = train_features.pop('mean Cd')
test_labels = test_features.pop('mean Cd')

# Only one hidden layer will be used
# 4 nodes are used because of the rule of thumb:
# Hidden layer nodes = (No. of inputs + No. of outputs) / 2
model = Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(4, activation="sigmoid", name="hidden_layer"),
        layers.Dense(1, name="output_layer"),
    ]
)

# Compile the model to static graph
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse")

# Train the model using 80% of the training data
model.fit(
    train_features, train_labels,
    epochs=100,
    # Calculate validation results on 20% of the training data
    validation_split = 0.2)

# Test the model on up to now unused test data
# Loss on test data should be close to loss on
# on validation data during training, otherwise
# the model is overfitted
print("Test:")
model.evaluate(test_features,test_labels)
# Save the model for later use
model.save('tmp/model')
```

At first it looks like the training actually went well. The loss is going down nicely and I have similar loss on the test dataset which I did not use for the training.

However if I now test my model by just plugging in different inputs, the output only changes slightly, although that was not the case for the original data.

E.g. the first 5 lines of the data get predicted like this:

```
model.predict(x=[[15,21,15,15,21,21,200]])
array([[0.00913189]], dtype=float32)
model.predict(x=[[15,21,15,15,21,21,400]])
array([[0.00913231]], dtype=float32)
model.predict(x=[[15,21,15,15,21,21,600]])
array([[0.00913231]], dtype=float32)
model.predict(x=[[15,21,15,15,21,23,200]])
array([[0.00913177]], dtype=float32)
model.predict(x=[[15,21,15,15,21,23,400]])
array([[0.00913231]], dtype=float32)
```

which is far away of the range of results that can be observed in the original data from 0.0075 to 0.010.

Why is my model not sensitive enough regarding the inputs. How can I get better model behavior?

EDIT: For the better understanding of the data I made a small Dash app.

Now if I change one parameter, e.g. like here `x3` I can observe, that increasing `x3` reduces the drag for the given combination of all other parameters.
[image: Original data for x3=21]
[image: Original data for x3=23]
[image: Original data for x3=25]
So there should be a relationship in the data, in my opinion. However it is definitely highly non-linear as `Re` might switch its influence when I change e.g. `y3`:
[image: Original data for x3=25, y3=21]
[image: Original data for x3=25, y3=23]

I also tried to use more nodes (16 in each layer) and two layers, however the results then look something like this for all parameter combinations:

[image: Model results for model with 2 layers, 16 nodes each]

What else can I do to correctly reflect the behavior of the original data?

EDIT 2:

I added 6 additional inputs in the form of `df["x1Re"] = (df["x1"]-np.mean(df["x1"]))*(df["Re"]-np.mean(df["Re"]))` for all parameters `x1`, `x2` and so on. With two hidden layers and 16 nodes in each layer, the estimation now looks like this:

[image: Model estimation with additional inputs and 2 layers with 16 nodes each]

It also looks seem to look like this for all input combinations, so it is not sensitive to the input.

[image: MSE of model]
[image: Loss of model]

Comment: Are you sure there has to be a relationship between these things and mean Cd?  Possibly a silly comment, but that would be one possible explanation if they actually have no explanatory ability at all.  Would also explain why your test error would look like the train error (normally they should diverge at some point where you get overfit).  Apologies if I've missed something, I'm not super familiar with Python, so might be misinterpreting what you're doing, just occurred to me that it was worth suggesting...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I made an edit to address that point.

Comment: OK, so unfortunately I skipped the fluid dynamics module at uni!  And my neural networks are a bit rusty, so just some preliminary thoughts.  But it's important to understand that a neural network is fundamentally an additive model.  They *can* in principle model any relationship but my gut feeling is that an interaction like you are seeing (Re effect flips) would be very heavy for it and it would need a lot of hidden units and a lot of data to be able to capture it.  What happens if you include only those cases where Re has a positive effect?

Comment: You could have some fun designing some kind of hybrid model that encoded the fact that there is an interaction specifically for Re.   Though, thinking about it, I *think* you could do that by including extra predictors in your model that were multiples of Re with each of the other predictors (though it'll have an easier time of it if you subtract the mean from each before multiplying).  I'm not 100% sure if that would be enough, but could be worth a shot!  It's what we do in regressions to capture an interaction and makes it possible to build the interaction additively from the inputs.

Comment: *If* that works -- I'll write you a proper answer explaining why it works.

Comment: If I understand you correctly I could try to add 6 additional inputs, that are x1*Re, x2*Re and so on, correct?

Comment: Yes, but i would do (x1-mean(x1))*(Re-mean(Re)) -- they'll have the same effect, but (I *think* -- again very rusty and might be jumbling things up) it decouples them so you have a less long-thin error valley, which is easier for the optimiser.  The key point to understand is that your network is really just trying to assemble the whole relationship from four sigmoid functions, stretched upwards and across, then added.  So even then, it might be too complex a relationship, but it would be interesting to see if the problem was caused by ups and downs cancelling each other.

Comment: Alright, I will try this as soon as I'm back on my PC. Thanks for help!

Comment: Let me know how it goes!  Btw, though it's fun trying to get the neural network to work, it's always worth posing the question: is this really a job for a neural network? :)  It's really just a fancy regression, but you have a model that can give you better answers already...

Comment: Hehe, yeah this is mainly just for fun. I wanted to dig a little into neural networks and as fluid flow is my main topic of work, I made this flow around triangle situation up. There might however be actual applications for stuff like this, as CFD calculations often take very long. Using a neural network as a kind of surrogate model can be interesting in some specific cases.

Comment: At the very least, it's a great educational example as we have a ground truth for what it *should* come out like, and some interesting interactions to try to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @PhilAssheton I added an image of the result with the additional inputs. Unfortunately this seems also not so successful.

Comment: Hey at least you got some shape now! Without seeing everything properly (ideally, a reproducible example), it's hard to figure out what is going on. Might just be too chaotic a system for the NN to capture, might be a bug in your code (are you still subtracting the same original mean from your X1 etc when running the new examples? That's very important), might be too few data points... Btw if it were me I'd probably not be randomly sampling my training set but rather generate some new in-between grid points for test set... Etc etc

Comment: What does the MSE look like btw? What did it look like before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124977/discussion-between-axel-and-phil-assheton).